# Trying to have a video switch (roll over) upon hovering over a button that links to a different page

Tags: javascript, css, hover, rollover

ooof... To start- I am trying to teach myself css and bits of java after decades of knowing basic html. I am working on updating my webpage... I've found coding and frankensteined a bunch of stuff and have made most sense of it. SO yes my coding is kinda messy, BUT things are looking good. I want to add some fun/ interesting splash in between parent and children pages... this is where I'm coming into some trouble.

I figured out how to lay video on top of eachother and under a png with a cutout (what I'm using on my page is filler- not what I'm actually using or sized right for the end product) via grid. Now I would like to have the videos change when any button is hovered over (that goes to another page). They are not connected via child or parent. I've watched hours of video on youtube and read so many forums... I'm learning backwards, but I am teachable. :D

Help?

website is still under construction- still filling it up... and editing projects...

[site](http://www.burntflower.net/art.html)

thank you in advance for your time!
~Cari

I've tried learning through osmosis.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)